# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function jquery.min.js:4

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, undefined

This error randomly popped up while I was in the midst of making this project, I for the life of me I can't figure out what's causing it, and none of the numerous other questions about this have shed any light on it.

I've got a progress bar that runs to it's max based off a timer, and for whatever reason it seems to now reject code that previously worked just fine in the progressbar complete function.

This is the full error I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function   jquery.min.js:4
  f.fx.step                                       jquery.min.js:4
  h                                               jquery.min.js:4
  f.fx.custom                                     jquery.min.js:4
  f.fx.show                                       jquery.min.js:4
  g                                               jquery.min.js:4
  f.extend.dequeue                                jquery.min.js:2
  (anonymous function)                            jquery.min.js:2
  e.extend.each                                   jquery.min.js:2
  e.fn.e.each                                     jquery.min.js:2
  f.fn.extend.queue                               jquery.min.js:2
  f.fn.extend.animate                             jquery.min.js:4
  f.fn.extend.show                                jquery.min.js:4
  html.rbar.progressbar.complete                      game.js:183
  t.Widget._trigger              jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js:6
  t.widget._refreshValue         jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js:6
  (anonymous function)           jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js:6
  t.widget._setOptions           jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js:6
  (anonymous function)           jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js:6
  t.Widget.option                jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js:6
  (anonymous function)           jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js:6
  x.extend.each                               jquery-2.0.3.js:590
  x.fn.x.each                                 jquery-2.0.3.js:237
  t.fn.(anonymous function)      jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js:6
  update                                              game.js:323
```

And these are the lines that appear to be causing the issue:

Line 183: `$("#result2").show("drop",{direction: "up"},200).text("+10% Upgrade Efficiency");`

Line 189: `$("#result1").show("drop",{direction: "up"},200).text("Coin-switch unlocked.");`

Line 197: `$("#result4").show("drop",{direction: "up"},200).text("+"+addCommas(pool_increase/1000)+" GH/s Pool Power.");`

Line 206: `$("#result1").show("drop",{direction: "up"},200).text("Mining Pools unlocked.");`

Line 207: `$("#result4").show("drop",{direction: "up"},200).text(addCommas(pool_startamount/1000)+" GH/s Pool found.");`

Line 217: `$("#result3").show("drop",{direction: "up"},200).text("+"+addCommas(cloud_increase/1000)+" GH/s Cloud Max.");`

In particular, the `"drop",{direction: "up"}` code seems to be the source, as removing it prevents the error.

To note, Line 323 is `html.rbar.progressbar("option","value",game.research.timer);`

**EDIT:** It appears the problem lies within any jQuery UI effect, if I put in just the effect name (e.g. `.show("drop");`) it'll work, but act like a regular `.show();`, whereas if options or the delay in (`.show("drop",{direction: "upyours"},"slow");`) the error occurs. This also happens with `.effect("drop")` where it will error no matter the effect input.

Comment: @elchanrs Added it to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure on this, but it looks like you are trying to pass an object {} into something expecting text.

Comment: what is the 200 supposed to indicate? The third parameter in the show method should be the function to call on completion, no?

Comment: It looks like  you may be using the .show() syntax from jquery-ui, which differs from  jQuery.

Comment: @adrichman It indicates the delay of the animation in miliseconds, and the jquery-ui syntax is what I checked for code validity. It should be fine. see http://www.jqueryui.com/show/ & http://api.jqueryui.com/drop-effect/

Comment: if game.research.timer is the function invoked on completion, and completion occurs at 183, that could indicate that your timer method is undefined.

Comment: @adrichman game.research.timer is a variable, and all variables are declared before use.

Comment: @LukeZaz But a declared variable without a value assignment is still undefined.

Comment: @adrichman It appears to have a value when the error happens. Also, the error would've happened much sooner had that been the issue - this one occurs when the progress bar completes, however the timer variable is utilized to fill the progress bar in the first place, and works just fine there.